# Distorting a gradient

Tags: inkscape, svg, gradient

In Inkscape, is it possible to distort a gradient so it follows a shape, instead of starting and ending outside of the shape? I would like to avoid raster effects if at all possible.

This image is an example of what I want, the rectangle on the left is the shape before, and the shape on the right is what I want after moving two of the control points.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Inkscape does have mesh gradient functionality, but it is disabled by default. It is also kind of a pain to get exactly what I want and if I try to copy the object with the gradient, the gradient on the copy disappears.

To enable it, add this to share/keys/default.xml:

```
<bind key="m" modifiers="Ctrl" action="ToolMesh" display="true" />
<bind key="m" modifiers="Alt" action="Mesh_Prefs" display="true" />
```

Are there any better solutions to do what I want?

Comment: It seems to work only for newer Cairo versions (i.e. not in Win 32, see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1335954)), but it could be a solution.